# C reference. Error

Tags: c, reference

I'm stuck with my code for 20 minutes.

What's wrong with this simple C code?

```
void function (char & reference_to_something) {}
```

error:

```
expected ';' , ',' or ')' before '&' token
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not have references; C++ does.

Comment: Occasionally, it's a nuisance.  If you want C++, though, you know where to find it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no semantic difference between reference and pointer except for the fact that reference does not allow changing its address. Use the pointer instead and you'll be just fine.

```
void function (char* pointer_to_something) {}
```

Comment: The biggest difference is often at the call site; you need an explicit `&` (typically) with C, where C++ does not require anything special at the call site: `function(&c)` in C with a pointer vs `function(c)` in C++ with a reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a pointer, you can do like this:

```
void function (char * reference_to_something) { return; }
```